# Python libraries interdependency resolution issue

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have the following section in my `setup.py` for `mymainapp`:

```
 install_requires=[
          'myapp1==0.2.0',
          'myapp2==0.6.0',
...
]
```

Here are the corresponding `install_requires` sections for those two app/dependencies:

`myapp1 0.2.0`

```
install_requires=[
  sas==1.2.0'
],
```

`myapp2 0.6.0`

```
install_requires=[
   sas==1.6.1'
],
```

Then I am performing

```
pip wheel --find-links="wheelhouse/" --wheel-dir="wheelhouse/" .
```

(using of course the `setup.py` of `mymainapp`)

And when trying to install the app using the created `wheelhouse`

```
pip install --find-links=wheelhouse --no-index mymainapp
```

it fails with the following error:

```
Collecting sas==1.6.1 (from `myapp2`==0.6.0->mymainapp)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sas==1.6.1 (from myapp2==0.6.0->mymainapp) (from versions: 1.2.0)
```

Given that it successfully installed **both** `myapp1` and `myapp2` as dependencies of `mymainapp`, - i.e. created both `.whl` files -  why it fails to find one of **their** dependencies?

(**TL;DR**: `mymainapp` has depdendencies on `myapp1` and `myapp2` which in turn have dependency on **different** versions of the same app (`sas`) )